# MySQL connections disconnection causing high CPU

Tags: mysql, rds

In one of our MySQL server we are observing a odd behaviour the connections are mostly around 3000 - however when we terminate (we do blue-green deployments) around 1000 connections drop and that causes the CPU to become spiky with 3k connections it was at ~30% but after dropping connections it starts jumping from 50% - 90%.

Our write load is 1200 IOPS and read is 400 IOPS.

Is there any MySQL internal behavior that can cause server to behave odd when connections disconnect?

Comment: You might get a better answer over on [DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) "_Q&A for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community_" . I'll pop the question into our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-hat--consultancy-) and see what happens.

Comment: Check for rollback. When you have a transaction started and you close the connection, the transaction will be rolled back automatically.